# Two JS files with window.onload = function() are conflicting

Tags: javascript, html

I had this script to open and close my side menu, it had an HTML built-in event handler. Then I read that built-in event handlers are old-fashioned. So I reworked it to pure JS.

I made my own event handler, which should've worked, but it returned an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null.

Then I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778888/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-onclick-of-null) that maybe I should add to JS:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    // your code 
};
```

I added the function and it worked.

But then it suddenly stopped working after I added another JS for an accordion with the same `window.onload` since it didn't want to work without the function or when `<script>` wasn't inside the `<head>`.

I'm new to JS. Can you help me? Is it possible to make both js work without `window.onload` and keep them inside `<head>`?

Comment: Put your `<script>` just before the end of your `</body>`. This way you are sure all the HTML is present before running any script on it. No need for `window.onload`

Comment: If the first comment did not help: please share more details

Comment: The mentioned duplicate also has a way to keep using `window.onload`, instead of replacing it with `addEventListener`, if you really want to do it that way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683336/1427878

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onload`, as you have noticed, can only hold a single event handler. When you assign a new one, any existing one is overwritten.

Instead, use `addEventListener()`, which, as the name already says, **adds** a listener when called.

So instead of

```
window.onload = function () { ... };
```

just do

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... });
```

Please note that the `load` event might not be the optimal lifecycle hook in your case. `load` comes after `DOMContentLoaded`, and `load` waits until all external assets like images, stylesheets, fonts etc are loaded.

More often than that what you really want is to make sure to wait until all the DOM elements are readily parsed and available. For that purpose, the DOM API has the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... });
```

Instead of working with listeners like this, you also have two other options:

1. Either place your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag:

   ```
   <script src="path/to/my.js"></script>
   ```
2. Or use the `defer` attribute on your `<script>`, which allows to keep `<script>` inside the `<head>`:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="path/to/my.js" defer></script>
  ...
</head>
```